# Physics RayCast Moves Object towards the camera or origin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the code below in the `Update` function :

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
{
    mouseFollow = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(mouseFollow, out hit))
    {
        target_point = hit.point;   
        if (blade_created == false)
        {
            blade = (GameObject)Instantiate(Blade, target_point, Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            blade_created = true;
        }

        if (blade != null) blade.transform.position = hit.point;
        Debug.DrawLine(mouseFollow.origin, target_point, Color.red);
    }
}
```

The blade GameObject follows the mouse position correctly, but when I am holding down the button(fire1), with no mouse moving effect, the blade (GameObject) moves towards the camera which is origin of Intersected Ray. Why this causes ?
Maybe there is a problem with `RaycastHit` Instance?

I have initialized it both in "Update function scope" and in top of the code ( global scope.).but nothing changed.
How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Its the `if (blade != null)` condition. When you check for null blade. it will return false always as you have created the blade on first click. And problem starts. After we create a blade, we are JUST keep on checking for the `hit.point` and transform blade to that point. We should also check for the object on which hit occurs.

In your case, suppose there is a Plane on background. So there we got the `hit.point` on it. But as soon as we get the Instance of a blade we found the "Blade(Clone)" as the hit object and it keeps on transform the Blade to the new hit point of itself (ie on surface of that Blade not on the origin of the Blade).

You should check for the hit object before transforming the blade as following code.

```
if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
        {
            target_point = hit.point;   
            if (blade_created == false)
            {
                blade = (GameObject)Instantiate(Blade, target_point, Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
                blade_created = true;
            }

            if (blade != null && hit.transform.name != "Blade(Clone)") 
                blade.transform.position = hit.point;

        }
    }
```